# about the concept of an FC element

Tags: group-theory

I have a problem on the notion of FCelement.

let $G$ be a group and $a\in G$ of finite order, so $\langle a \rangle$ is an FC group.

My qeustion is : Why $a$ could be a non FC element in $G$?

Comment: It could have infinitely many conjugates in $G$. Why not?

Comment: i couldn't make the difference between a finite group is FC and it has a finite conjugates

Comment: $\langle a \rangle$ is a finite group. It is a subgroup of the group $G$, which could be infinite. So there could be infinitely many distinct elements $g^{-1}ag$ with $g \in G$.

Comment: i can understand taht if a subgroup is an FC group, its elements are not necessarily FC elements of the whole group

Comment: You should define/explain what "FC" is.

Comment: $a$ is an fc element means that it has a finite number of conjugates, i.e $|G:C_{G} (a)|$ finite

Answer (score 2):

Consider the group of all permutations of natural numbers, $G=S_\mathbb{N}$. Let $a$ be the permutation swapping $1$ and $2$ and fixing all other numbers. Then:

- $a$ has order $2$; but
- $a$ has infinitely many conjugates (in particular, $a$ is conjugate to every *other* permutation which swaps two elements and preserves all others).

Comment: thnks, now i've a better look to the consept